# Изменить список JList в зависимости от JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить список JList в зависимости от JComboBox? Мне нужно написать простой словарик, где список слов на одном языке приведен через JList, а выбрать язык можно через JComboBox и в зависимости от того какой язык выбрали, этот список нужно поменять на выбранный.

Примерный вид:

[image: Dictionary]

FormClass.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class FormClass extends JFrame {
JTextField text;
JButton button;
JList list;
JComboBox combo;
JPanel panel;
String[] eng, rus, temp;
String line;
int tempIndex, choice;

public FormClass() throws FileNotFoundException{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    text = new JTextField();
    button = new JButton("Search");

    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    temp = new String[(int) file.length()];

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        line = sc.nextLine();
        temp = line.split("=");
    }
    rus = new String[temp.length];
    eng = new String[temp.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(i % 2 != 0){
            rus[i] = temp[i];
        }else{
            eng[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }

    list = new JList(eng);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tempIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
            text.setText(rus[tempIndex + 1]);
        }
    });

    combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.addItem("Eng");
    combo.addItem("Rus");
    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(button);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(combo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

MainClass.java

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FormClass form = new FormClass();
        form.setSize(300, 300);
        form.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать лист и дать ему DefaultListModel.

```
DefaultListModel mod=new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(mod);
```

Написать код для слушателя JComboBox. Например, такой.

```
@Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        mod.clear();
        if(combo.getSelectedItem().equals("Rus")){
            for(String g:rus){
                System.out.println(g);
                mod.addElement(g);
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("eng");
    }
});
```

Вот только мне кажется, что вы неправильно считываете с файла.

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    line = sc.nextLine();
    temp = line.split("=");
}
```

У вас массив temp каждый шаг цикла инициализируется заново. То есть в конце цикла массив temp будет содержать только данные с последней строки.
P.s. Или можно создать лист для каждого языка и просто менять их.

Comment: Вы правы, вынес temp за цикл, теперь нормально записывает, спасибо)